# Find the elements have the same value in two numpy arrays python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays A and B, I want to find in B which rows have the same value **(second and third columns)** as A. For example, in B I found that 2 & 3 (at the first row) and 8 & 9 (at the 4th row). So I need to print out the row that has the same values which is 0 and 3

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3],            
              [7, 8, 9]]) 

B = np.array([[0, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [4, 5, 6],               
               [1, 8, 9]])
```

This is my approach:

```
results = []
for k in range(0,A.shape[0]):
    i = np.where(np.all(np.isclose(B[:,1:3],A[k,1:3], atol=0.5), axis=1))[0]
    #print(i)
    for i in i:
        results.append(i)
print(results)
```

It can be print out [0, 3] (which is correct)

But when I change A to

```
A = np.array([[ 111,  67108864,  33554495,  100663297,  50331709,  32,  16777216],
 [ 112,  67108864,  33554475,  100663297,  50331709,  48,  16777248],
 [ 113,  67108864,  33554455,  100663297,  50331709,  16,  16777232],
 [ 114,  67108864,  33554435,  100663297,  50331709,  8,  16777264],
 [ 120,  67108865,  33554455,  100663297,  50331709,  40,  16777224]])
```

And B to

```
B = np.array([[ 54, 67108864, 33554495, 100663297, 50331711, 0, 16777216],
 [ 55, 67108864, 33554493, 100663297, 50331710, 32, 16777248],
 [ 56, 67108864, 33554491, 100663297, 50331709, 16, 16777232],
 [ 57, 67108864, 33554489, 100663297, 50331708, 48, 16777264],
 [ 58, 67108864, 33554487, 100663297, 50331707, 8, 16777224],
 [ 59, 67108864, 33554485, 100663297, 50331706, 40, 16777256],
 [ 60, 67108864, 33554483, 100663297, 50331705, 24, 16777240],
 [ 61, 67108864, 33554481, 100663297, 50331704, 56, 16777272],
 [ 62, 67108864, 33554479, 100663297, 50331703, 4, 16777220],
 [ 63, 67108864, 33554477, 100663297, 50331702, 36, 16777252],
 [ 64, 67108864, 33554475, 100663297, 50331701, 20, 16777236],
 [ 65, 67108864, 33554473, 100663297, 50331700, 52, 16777268],
 [ 66, 67108864, 33554471, 100663297, 50331699, 12, 16777228],
 [ 67, 67108864, 33554469, 100663297, 50331698, 44, 16777260],
 [ 68, 67108864, 33554467, 100663297, 50331697, 28, 16777244],
 [ 69, 67108864, 33554465, 100663297, 50331696, 60, 16777276],
 [ 70, 67108864, 33554463, 100663297, 50331695, 2, 16777218]])
```

However, I got this results:

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

I don't know why is it!

Any one can explain?

Thank you

Comment: It is a double loop. And one of your loops has 5 rows and the other has 17. 5*17=85
It compares eachrow of your first array with the each row of your second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try np.equal instread of np.isclose. Isclose is valid in case where two arrays are element-wise equal within a tolerance so this is why it does not work in your case :

```
for k in range(0,A.shape[0]):
      i = np.where(np.all(np.equal(B[:,1:3],A[k,1:3]), axis=1))[0]
      for i in i:
          results.append(i)
```

Comment: In fact, i need the np.isclose for the number just like 67108864.4 and I don't know how to do without np.isclose. However, the answer is correct that I need, and I accept it like a solution. Thank you very much

Comment: If you just say that ok 94.0 is equal with 94.3 then you can use an operation like round and round them all to have integers (before you compare them). Otherwise you keep the isclose but adjust the torelance depending what you assume that is equal. Thanks:)